# Android sdk activity flow

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, exit, back

Can someone help me replicate the following scenario:

I'm having a activity A with some specific tasks from which the app goes to activity B. When the user goes to B and presses back the app should close (maybe meaning that activity A performed finish()). But in some cases the app (not on the user action) goes back to Activity A, with the state preserved to when it went to B. The thing is that the app can never know if it should preserve activity A to be re-displayed later or not.
Hope I made it clear. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate your Activity A every time in its onResume(). For persistence you can use SharedPreferences.

You can setup a BroadcastReceiver in Activity A which will call finish() for Activity A upon receiving a message. In the Activity B just before you close  you then send that message to Activity A's broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the Activity B with startActivityForResult() and in function of the result, when we come back to the activity A, Activity A finish() himself or not.

Comment: Yes, but instead of exiting the app it will pop to A and then exit. I don't know if it's the best approach. Still searching for another one. But, it's a solution, many thanks.

Comment: The Activity A will always be on the stack when you will launch the activity B, so, it will take no time to popup the activity A, it will very fast and finish instantly, you will never have the time to see the activity A or maybe on some very low configuration phones...